# How to load error trackers from script tag?

Tags: javascript, sentry, rollbar

I'm working on small .js which is going to be embedded on multiple websites, it will be loaded in a classic way - via script tag: `<script src="myscript.js"></script>` in sites body tag. I cannot add any more scripts to those sites.

I would like to track errors with error tracker such as [Sentry](https://sentry.io/), [Rollup](https://rollbar.com/) or [HoneyBadger](https://www.honeybadger.io/). However, all of them require being loaded with another script tag, most preferred before everything else.

**Note**: Those services need to load before everything else to catch errors property.

As I cannot add another script tag in the site's code, I need to execute their code inside my script, but before my actual script code.

I tried taking the content of HoneyBadger javascript library and putting it directly inside my file - it worked, however, I feel like it's terrible practice, as their code is written with modern browsers in mind, and mine supports older ones.

Is there any good way in my situation to load their .js externally?

Comment: `I feel like it's terrible practice` If you do it in a *proper* way, I think this is just fine - use a bundler like Webpack. Such methods are very common. (Using a build process will also let you transpile the library's code to ES5 automatically, which sounds like something you want)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that would work because of the way honeybadger.js v0.5 parses the script tag to get those attributes--it looks for the script tag in the dom when it's loaded.

Also, we've moved away from using the data- attributes in honeybadger.js v1.0, which was just released. In that version, you must use Honeybadger.configure to set your API key. Take a look at the new docs here:

https://docs.honeybadger.io/lib/javascript/integration/browser.html

I'd recommend going with v1.0, and using Honeybadger.configure for the configuration.